# Status bar under View in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, uistoryboard

Recently I found that the status bar is appearing below the uiview in storyboard (Please find the sample attached image) and also at run time in device as well as simulator.

Device
[image]

Storyboard

[image]

Any ideas how could that be resolved ? Is there something to do with storyboard properties?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from a device? I've never seen this before without some magic trickery.

Comment: can you try moving that uiview a bit down ?

Comment: @Fennelouski added device screenshot.

Comment: @Mr.T, yes moved it bit down but actually what is needed that everything should be under status bar no matter what! Which is default but I think there is something missing !!

Comment: The view is definitely stacked under the status bar. You can tell most easily by looking at the green in the battery icon. If you change the status bar content color to light then it should be more obvious.

Comment: how about usage of topLayout guide constraint ?

Answer (score 0):

Have u add any constraint?

So if I try to just place UIView in storyboard without constraint i got

[image]

But if I add some constraint like

[image]

I got correct result

[image]

Comment: What are you doing to get that Top Layout Guide option in IB?? I'm only seeing the "View (current distance...)" option.

Comment: "When laying out a storyboard scene, the Top Layout Guide object is available in the Interface Builder outline view as a child of the View Controller object." - look here [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide)